# How do I send a high priority inbox style notification on Android using FCM?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a high priority notification to Android devices using FCM and have it displayed in the system tray as an [Inbox style notification.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle)

FCM does not allow you to configure the Android notification style server side, so I must send the send the android system notification client side, to use NotificationManager API to send an inbox style notification.

The only way to do this without an automatic default style notification is to use FCM data messages. But the Firebase Flutter docs (I am trying to implement a solution for this on Android Native and Flutter, but a Android Native solution will suffice) indicate that data messages are low priority...

From the [flutterfire docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#background-messages):

> As mentioned above, data only messages are classed as "low priority".
> Devices can throttle and ignore these messages if your application is
> in the background, terminated, or a variety of other conditions such
> as low battery or currently high CPU usage.
>
> You should not rely on data only messages to be delivered. They should
> only be used to support your application's non-critical functionality,
> e.g. pre-fetching data so the next time the user opens your app the
> data is ready to be displayed and if the message never gets delivered
> then your app still functions and fetches data on open.

So it seems, based on the premises presented here, that it is impossible to send a high priority inbox style notification on Android. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already present in FireFly documents however it also depends on the brand of Android device being used to receive notification which also have their own priority of background tasks depending upon battery usage and other factors,
**The Answer from [FireFly documents](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages):-**

Message types#
A message payload can be viewed as one of three types:

Notification only message: The payload contains a notification property, which will be used to present a visible notification to the user.

**Data only message: Also known as a "silent message", this payload contains custom key/value pairs within the data property which can be used how you see fit. These messages are considered "low priority" (more on this later).
Notification & Data messages: Payloads with both notification and data properties.**

Based on your application's current state, incoming payloads require different implementations to handle them.

**Data only messages are considered low priority by devices when your application is in the background or terminated, and will be ignored. You can however explicitly increase the priority by sending additional properties on the FCM payload:
On Android, set the priority field to high.
On Apple (iOS & macOS), set the content-available field to true.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you still can. Even though data message is normal priority by default, you can still manually set it to `high` as stated in the [doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages:%7E:text=You%20can%20however%20explicitly%20increase%20the%20priority%20by%20sending%20additional%20properties%20on%20the%20FCM%20payload).